# Migrate Windows 8.1 from HDD to SSD Error

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, windows-8.1, uefi, migration

I’m trying to migrate my Notebook HDD (Asus q550lf-bbi7t07 with Windows 8.1 OEM) to my new SSD drive (SSD Intel 530 Series 240Gb).

I tried to clone the original drive to SSD drive with many tools:

- List item
- Intel® Data Migration Software
- EaseUS
- Acronis
- Paragon Migrate OS to SSD 4.0 (I bought the full license)
- MiniTool Partition Wizard
- GParted
- Asus Backtracker (installation failure)

In all cases Windows worked properly for 2 or 3 minutes and then its throws me a “blue screen of death” and redirect me to the BIOS (The BIOS does not recognize the drive until I turn off and turn back the PC, then everything repeats...)

I tried to install a clean Windows 8, but I can't because when I have to select the Partition to be installed, its throws me an error (code 0x80070002)

I think it may be an error related to UEFI.

Any of you went through the same situation as me? What should I do?

EDIT: Disk Management Screenshot
[image: Disk Management Screenshot]

Thanks

Comment: Just to verify you created a complete clone of the hdd and restored the image to the ssd?

Comment: Yes, I also tried it

Comment: How large is the source drive?  If you copied 250GB of the source drive sector by sector it should have worked.

Comment: The source drive have 1TB, but on a trial I reduced OS partition to 200GB with the same result. Currently I have 40GB used.

Comment: So you have a single partition of 200GB and the rest of the 1TB drive is unused space without a partition.  When you created the image you selected `sector by sector` correct?  What version of Acrnois did you use, because the process I described, has worked for lots of people.

Comment: Yes, I have 2 smalls system patitions and 200GB OS partition, the rest of the 1TB drive is unused space without a partition. Acronis was my fist option (3 weeks ago...), I didn't remember if I selected that option :/. I used "Acronis True Image Home 2014".

Comment: Honestly `Paragon Migrate OS to SSD 4.0` also should have done the job.  Can you list the partitions and/or provide a screenshot of the disk management, showing the layout of both devices?  Are you able to boot to the TB drive, while the SSD is installed, we might have a case where your system is unsure of which installation you actually want to boot to.

Comment: Did you update the SSD firmware? Sometimes that helps.

Comment: OK, I have uploaded a screenshot. The actual clonation was made with Paragon Migrate OS to SSD 4.0. I boot with the SSD and connect the original drive as a external USB.

Comment: I didn't update the fimware the ssd, I'll find out if Intel 530 has any.

Comment: Which disk is the SSD?  Because its odd you have two recovery partitions yet the source disk has one.

Comment: SSD in Disk 0. But the Recovery Partition didn't work, If I copy the Recovery to another drive, The restore in the SSD fails. I also try to create an restore point with "History File" and its says that the recovery partition is Corrupted :/

Comment: @cybernard I update the SSD firmware and clone with `Acronis True Image 2014` again, with the same results :(

@Ramhound When I performed the clonation I didn't see the `sector by sector` option, only asked about src and dst drives.

Comment: What stop code do you get on the "blue screen of death"?

Comment: The error code is CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED

Answer (score 1):

In my case, "Samsung Migration" doesn't work on windows 8.1.
Ofcourse there's no problem on Win 8.
But the "DriveClone" works on Windows 8.1 properly.
I recommend you to use it.
"Ease us" worked good too.

Comment: I tried using `Clonezilla` for disk cloning but It didn't help me so I used `EaseUS Todo Backup` software and here you can check Its details https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/how-to-clone-windows-8-hard-drive.html